# Eclipse - Android emulator not launching application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to run the default Hello World application in my emulator using eclipse.

My Project is set to:

- Generic - 3.7"WVGA (480 x 800 hdpi)
- API 19: Android 4.4.2

and here is my emulator settings:

[image]

But when I launch this emulator with my application, it takes a super long time to load, All I see in my android emulator screen is just Android:

[image]

In my console all it says is: Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus' and does nothing else, its been sitting like this for half an hour and I have tried restarted the eclipse application a few times and still just Android. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have had this same issue with the emulator. Try debugging on an android device. The emulator has never worked for me.

Comment: I don't have an android device :(

Comment: It needs lots of memory and processing power. I had this issue up to 4gb of RAM. My issue was resolved after hardware upgrade. Try on  different/powerful pc with same settings for emulator. And yes, usb debugging won't be a problem.

Comment: For not having android device, you can try RTL(Remote Testing Lab) provided by samsung. They reserve real phone remotely for testing for you .

Comment: I am using a Mac Processor 2.8 Ghz Quad-Core Intel Xeon Memory of 14 GB 800 Mhz DDR2 RB-DIMM

Comment: You could try http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: In that case, try other type of devices settings. 14 GB should be enough . I have 16 gig and it takes less than a minute. Also give it a shot to use SnapShot option in your emulator.

Answer (score 1):

First option:

Download the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator from the Android SDK Manager ( it's in Extras )

go to your SDK file and locate the file and click it to instill it

Then you will see a new option for the CPU/ABI  ( Android wear Intel x86 ) 
Pick it and run your emulator and it will be faster now.

Second option:

in the AVD , pick ( 3.2" HVGA slider (ADP1) ) device instead of Nexus

and it should run faster now !

Good Luck.

Comment: Change the Emulator AVD or the Projects AVD or both?

Comment: Both should be the same ( AVD = Android Virtual Device ) , just create new AVD device

Answer (score 0):

The Android Virtual Device emulator is known for being very slow and it always takes a long time to load.

If you really wish to work on the emulator, when creating a new device select the **Snapshot** option, which will save your current device state when you shut it down, and that should allow the emulator to boot up quickly (you will have to wait for it to load for the first time, though).

And although this option exists, I really recommend that you buy an Android device for debugging purposes (I bet you can find used 2013 models for a really low price)

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem because of low RAM. I resolved that by using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

It's much lighter and faster than your AVD. Also, if you need Google's apps (maps, play) in your emulator, you can always add them. Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/) for that